# Spring: Do I need @EnableAspectJAutoProxy with Compile time weaving?

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, caching, aspectj

I've looked around the internet and found a few suggestions, and also tried different configurations, but I'm totally unsure if it works correctly.

**pom.xml** (full pom.xml: http://pastebin.com/5Y2qksTH ):

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                        <runOnConfiguration>true</runOnConfiguration>
                                        <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <Xlint>warning</Xlint>
                <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I've added

```
<execute>
    <runOnConfiguration>true</runOnConfiguration>
    <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
</execute>
```

because before it seemed like I always had to do `Project -> Clean` in Eclipse and afterwards `Tomcat -> Clean`. Else it always executed my cached method. Now it seems to work automatically.

**CacheableConfig.java**:

```
@EnableCaching(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
public class CacheableConfig implements CachingConfigurer {
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("testCache");
    }

    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new SimpleKeyGenerator();
    }
}
```

**AppConfig.java**:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {}
```

Without `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` it didn't work at all.

**MyTestServiceImpl.java**:

```
@Service
public class MyTestServiceImpl implements MyTestService {
    @Scheduled(initialDelay=10000, fixedDelay=30000)
    public void a() {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("START");
        System.out.println("returned: " + b(0));
        System.out.println("returned: " + b(1));
        System.out.println("returned: " + b(0));
        System.out.println("returned: " + b(1));
        System.out.println("returned: " + b(2));
        System.out.println("END: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    }

    @Cacheable("testCache")
    public int b(int i) {
        System.out.println("INSIDE CACHED METHOD");
        i++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
        return i;
    }
}
```

Note: I just use `@Scheduled` in order to automatically invoke the method multiple times.

**Output:**

```
START
2014-03-01 15:53:25,796 DEBUG    o.s.c.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource: 109 - Adding cacheable method 'b' with attribute: [CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless='']
2014-03-01 15:53:25,797 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 0 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
INSIDE CACHED METHOD
returned: 1
2014-03-01 15:53:27,798 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 1 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
INSIDE CACHED METHOD
returned: 2
2014-03-01 15:53:29,799 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 0 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
2014-03-01 15:53:29,799 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 0 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
returned: 1
2014-03-01 15:53:29,799 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 1 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
2014-03-01 15:53:29,799 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 1 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
returned: 2
2014-03-01 15:53:29,799 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 2 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
INSIDE CACHED METHOD
returned: 3
END: 6018

START
2014-03-01 15:54:01,801 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 0 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
2014-03-01 15:54:01,801 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 0 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
returned: 1
2014-03-01 15:54:01,801 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 1 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
2014-03-01 15:54:01,801 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 1 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
returned: 2
2014-03-01 15:54:01,801 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 0 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
2014-03-01 15:54:01,802 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 0 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
returned: 1
2014-03-01 15:54:01,802 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 1 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
2014-03-01 15:54:01,802 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 1 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
returned: 2
2014-03-01 15:54:01,802 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 2 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
2014-03-01 15:54:01,802 TRACE            o.s.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect: 318 - Computed cache key 2 for operation CacheableOperation[public int MyTestServiceImpl.b(int)] caches=[testCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
returned: 3
END: 1
```

This basically looks okay:

- First call of `a()` takes 6 seconds, because `b()` gets called effectively 3 times.
- Second call of `a()` takes 1ms, because everything comes from cache.
- Return values are okay.

**Questions**:

1. Why are those TRACE logs `Computed cache key x for operation ...` there always **two** times? Looks to me like the computation method gets called twice?!
2. Is the configuration okay? Because I'm not really sure if this will always work as expected, especially because I had to use `Project -> Clean` and `Tomcat -> Clean` sometimes. (else it just ignored the `@Cacheable` annotation and simple called the method)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your current setup will never work with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`. Spring AOP uses proxies to apply aspects. Your `@Scheduled` calls the method internally and as such will never pass through the proxy and you will never have caching.

Next to that you use compile time weaving so you shouldn't use `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` as the aspects are already weaved in. If that isn't working you have a problem in the setup of your pom together with your Eclipse.

Trying to get Eclipse and Maven working together is (or can be) a daunting task. Regarding AspectJ and Maven see [aspectj-maven-plugin not covered by lifecycle in Kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613685/aspectj-maven-plugin-not-covered-by-lifecycle-in-kepler) and [this blog](http://ridgetopsolutions.com/blog/2013/02/12/getting-started-with-aspectj-and-maven/) might also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. **1.** So if I understand correctly, I should delete `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` because I want to use compile time weaving. Eclipse and Maven are working together for everything else (i.e. generating class files for querying the database). **2.** The `@Scheduled` method was indeed placed there to call the `@Cacheable` method internally, because this is a scenario which only works using AspectJ. When using a standard AOP proxy this should never ever call the `AnnotationCacheAspect`. So I think that AspectJ with `@Cacheable` works somehow?!

Comment: If you use compile (or load time) weaving it will work, not with the default proxy approach. Maybe I should rephrase but getting eclipse to work together with all your maven plugins can be a pain. (That is one of the reasons why I switched to IntelliJ it has way better Maven support then Eclipse).

Comment: Now I'm confused `:-D` ... So here's what I want: Simple **compile time weaving**. Do I need `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`? Maybe you could elaborate a bit on what `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` does? The JavaDoc says `Enables support for handling components marked with AspectJ's @Aspect annotation, similar to functionality found in Spring's <aop:aspectj-autoproxy> XML element` which just sounds to me like *it enables AspectJ*.

Comment: EDIT: I just removed the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation from my `AppConfig.java` and it still works :) But I still don't understand what it's good for.

Comment: `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` is, as the name implies, used to enable Spring AOP in proxy mode. It will create proxies to apply AOP (see the Spring reference guide which explains this).