# Spring Roo and Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, spring-roo, spring-tool-suite

I downloaded Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 4.3.2 and than I installed the following plugins:

- Spring Tool Suite - http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.3/
- GWT - http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3

After that I downloaded  [Spring Roo 1.2.5](http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/spring-roo-1.2.5.RELEASE.zip). Next, I created a new Spring Roo project with help of the wizard and in the Roo shell appears:

*project --topLevelPackage sample.roo.flightapp --projectName flightapp-gwt --java 7 --packaging JAR*

However, Eclipse showed the following problems in pom.xml.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:compile (execution: default, phase: process-sources)    pom.xml /flightapp-gwt  line 182    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:test-compile (execution: default, phase: process-sources)   pom.xml /flightapp-gwt  line 182    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

[image]

How is it possible to fix the problem with "Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem"

Comment: This is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/13733232/977828 . Just wonder who make the mistake maybe someone could write a bug report.

Comment: The above solution caused this problem "additionalBuildCommands element of the maven-eclipse-plugin required" by executing this command "jpa setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Spring Roo bug: this just tell you that m2e eclipse plugin doesn't know how handle this maven plugins (when execute it on maven lifecycle).

The proof that is not Roo bug is simple: compile it using maven command-line version.

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613685/aspectj-maven-plugin-not-covered-by-lifecycle-in-kepler) to try to solve your problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Here is the tipicial case if different departments are pushing the s**t to the area of the other. Of course, your answer is factually perfect, and thus I gave you an upvote. But the real problem is: I want a roo project which builds clean and well on eclipse. For this real problem, you don't answer. You can't - the only real answer is: it doesn't work, because nobody want to do that.