# Eclipse not working after installing aspectj

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I installed AspectJ by following the answer to this question: [aspectj-maven-plugin not covered by lifecycle in Kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613685/aspectj-maven-plugin-not-covered-by-lifecycle-in-kepler)

Now Eclipse seems to be bugged, menus are missing, heck almost all of the interface is missing. Is there any way to bring it back?
[image: Here's a screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Your eclipse is showing a different perspective. On the upper right corner, click on the Java  button. That should bring back the windows that are missing.

Comment: Tried that but that resulted in even more missing elements, with the exception of a small bar on the right side.

Comment: Can you please post the log? It's the .metadata/.log file in your workspace.